# Adding strange characters to my temp file destination, is it a bug?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with adding some strange characters in my createTempFile() method. Here is the code

```
String destinationFileName = String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());

String fileExtension = "." + MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myFilePath.toString());

File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

File destinationFile = null;
try {
    destinationFile = File.createTempFile(destinationFileName, fileExtension, storageDir);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String myCurrentFilePath = destinationFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

The log is like this:

```
destinationFileName﹕ ae16ff26-7340-4cd5-80ea-963f29a93f71
fileExtension﹕ .mp4
myCurrentFilePath﹕ /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/ae16ff26-7340-4cd5-80ea-963f29a93f71-1081124956.mp4
```

Do you have an idea from where these `-1081124956` between `ae16ff26-7340-4cd5-80ea-963f29a93f71` and `.mp4` in `myCurrentFilePath` are comming. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the random number of long type that's generated by JDK. Its generated as follows:

```
long n = random.nextLong();
if (n == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
     n = 0;    
} else {
     n = Math.abs(n);
}
```

As per the javadocs, it says:

Once these adjustments have been
     * made the name of the new file will be generated by concatenating the
     * prefix, **five or more internally-generated characters**, and the suffix.

Answer (score 1):

[**From java doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))

> public static Path createTempFile(String prefix,
>                     String suffix,
>                     FileAttribute... attrs)
>                              throws IOException
>
> Creates an empty file in the default temporary-file directory, using the given prefix and
>   suffix to generate its name. The resulting Path is associated with the
>   default FileSystem. This method works in exactly the manner specified
>   by the createTempFile(Path,String,String,FileAttribute[]) method for
>   the case that the dir parameter is the temporary-file directory.

your `destinationFileName` is not file name but prefix to your temporary file

Answer (score 0):

From `createTempFile`.

The first argument is a *prefix*. `createTempFile` adds a random *suffix*, then the extension.

> `public static File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)`
>
> Creates an empty file in the default temporary-file directory, using the given prefix and suffix to generate its name.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)